# How to split up git repo and apply Maven submodules and Maven parent?

Tags: git, maven

I need some advice on how to configure multiple repo's such that they share a Maven parent and also are configured as submodules in a Maven root project.

I'm maintaining open source project [Simple Java Mail](http://simplejavamail.org) and as there are optional functions that are becoming larger and larger, I'm planning to split the project up into sub-modules each in there own GIT repo.

1. My first concern is that there should be a shared **Maven parent
   config** that handles all default test and build config as well as
   default test and utility dependencies. That is one extra repo I can
   think of.
2. Next, to easily build and release everything together with the same
   version numbers, I thought having a **Maven submodules** setup would
   be useful. How can I set this up in GIT repo's? My first thought
   would be another repo for the main/root Maven project which defines
   the submodules, then checkout this and all other repo's in the same
   folder and the main Maven project would find the module projects
   with `..\submodule-xyz` relative folders.

I have configured a similar setup before, but that was all in a single repository (in the good old Subversion days). Can anyone please advise on how to approach this best with split up repo's? Preferably I would have one repo for the parent pom and the main/root pom (is that common?). Is it preferable to combine with git submodules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term module is a bit overloaded here.

Yes, you can define in one repo a parent pom, declaring a [multi-module maven project](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module), each module referring to a subfolder.

Those subfolders can be created through `git submodule add` command, referencing each a remote repository where the sub-project is versioned.
The subfolders are relative to the root folder of the parent directory, but should not need `../`.

Each submodule repo can have its own `pom.xml`, which would reference the main project pom as a parent pom.

Comment: Ok, so you would recommend subfolders using git submodules over submodules not in subfolders not using git submodules, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @BennyBottema Yes, that allows you to update each submodule at its own pace, while keeping a coherent project through the main parent project. Regarding the pom.xml, see an example here: https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/BLOG/2013/07/22/Using+Aggregate+and+Parent+POMs (no git submodules innvolves: this is just to illustrate the use of parent pom in a maven multi-modules project)

Comment: Thank you. One more question, I don't have much experience with git submodules (I'll familiarize myself shortly), but is it easy to setup for new developers (ie. will they have to perform perform `git submodule add` manually each time they check out the repo's)?

Comment: Quoting [Github's own blog](https://blog.github.com/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/) on the subject: you can instruct _git clone_ to checkout submodules automatically: `git clone --recursive <project url>`

Comment: @BennyBottema Yes, that is the idea: `git clone --recursive` the first time, and `git submodule update --remote` each time they want to update the submodule to hte latest commit of the master branch.