# Nest Git repository in multi module maven project

Tags: git, maven, multi-module

I want to have a multi-module maven project which has for example the following structure.

```
+ parent
| - proj1
| - proj2
```

Now I want to have for the modules *parent*, *proj1* and *proj2* an own git repository to manage them individually.

What is the best approach here?

- Shall I simply create with `git init .` starting from the submodules (proj1, proj2) the repository for each module?
- Or Shall I create for the submodules (proj1, proj2) a repository and add them as submodules with `git submodule add` to the parent project and ignore them via `.gitigore`?
- Or is there even an other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shall I create for the submodules (proj1, proj2) a repository and add them as submodules with git submodule add to the parent project and ignore them via .gitigore?

That would be the preferred approach ([as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53456943/6309)), only if those projects have to evolve independently one from another.
And you don't have to modify your `.gitignore` file: no need to ignore those submodules.

Comment: But shall I really ignore the submodules?

Comment: No actually, you don't have to ignore them