# Manage multi module project

Tags: java, git, maven, spring-boot, jenkins

Current setup:

1. Maven
2. Spring Boot
3. Angular
4. 12 maven project + 1 Pom project
5. Git
6. Jenkin

Currently i have separate 13 project.
Every time if i have to setup on another machine then i have to clone each project individually. 
Also i did the Jenkin pipeline setup for auto build.

> Looking for
>
> 1. Once i clone the single pom/main project , all other project should get cloned
> 2. If i take pull of the main project then all other projects code should get updated
> 3. Child project should get head revision every time i start the jenkin 
>      build.
> 4. Want to keep separate repo for each sub projects so that it can be reuse in other project as i have multiple requirements.

Solution that i have thought of:

1. Maven Child projects
2. Git Sub modules

Issues facing in above solution

```
 1. Maven Child projects
 --> If we are using maven child projects then we are literally copying the sub projects in pom/main project. 
In this case i cannot reuse the project. Every time i have to clone the project to use it. 
For big project with number of team member working, merging issue will come.

2. Git Sub modules
--> This is best solution for me but when we create sub module it always point to commit not the head revision.
Every time i have to manually pull the latest code  push it to parent project.
This approach we can not use in Jenkins.
```

Is there best approach which can resolve all the issue.

Comment: I don't understand any of your points against a maven multimodule approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456841/how-to-split-up-git-repo-and-apply-maven-submodules-and-maven-parent post explains same on SO as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add git sub-modules by specifying what modules to be added from other repositories. A `.gitmodules` file will be created on root that will contain list of all submodules and other preferences of yours.

[Creating git submodules for projects in different repositories](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

There are set of commands available that you can use to sync up the git module and all it's sub-modules.

Set of steps that you could take is:

1. Add all submodules in project using `git submodule add [ssh or https path]` e.g.  `git submodule add https://github.com/test`
2. Add other submodules and push the changes
3. Fetch submodule content by running

```
git submodule init
 git submodule update
```

or alternatively run `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/chaconinc/MainProject` to get sub-modules as well

I would recommend that you read through [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) link and ensure your requirement is fulfilled by this.

Comment: I have already tried this. but everytime i have to take the update of each sub modules

Comment: I think you must spend sometime reading about same and do more exploration. Anyways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-to-pull-latest-of-all-git-submodules helps on that.